# How To Render HTML Elements from xsl value-of in XSLT?

Tags: javascript, java, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am working in generating a letter pdf using xsl-fo. I have a scenario where I need to format the text in my form like ex.Bold, Underline, Line-spaces, etc. I am using rich text editor to achieve this.

So my problem comes here when i generate the pdf, I have the formatted contents printing in the screen like.

Here is the code I used below.

```
<xsl-template match="bodyPrefix">
    <xsl:for-each select="paragraphprefix">
        <xsl-value-of select="section"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl-template>
```

Below is the result which is generated

```
<p>Hello</p>
<li>1</li>
<p>&nbsp;</li>
<p>&nbsp;</li>
<li>2</li>
```

where as i need to print it like

```
Hello

 - 1





 - 2
```

This html is just an example, in real time proper tags will be sent as input.
Any solutions or suggestions ?
Thanks for the help in advance !!!

Comment: Show us a minimal XML input document together with a minimal XSLT stylesheet and the generated XSL-FO document. Your first snippet looks like HTML, although even for HTML an `li` element without an `ol` or `ul` parent doesn't make any sense. And it is not clear how/where you transform your HTML input to XSL-FO.

Comment: To add to the comment from @MartinHonnen, what software are you using?